# Replace data into json file using PHP and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a json file (file1.json) which contain json data.
I would like to replace these data by new datas (newDataToStore).

I don't know how to do it using a php file (save.php file below) ?

Content of file1.json :

```
[
  {
    "key" : "test1",
    "desc": "desc1"
  },
  {
    "key" : "test2",
    "desc": "desc2"
  },
]
```

New json to write into json1.json file :

```
var newDataToStore = 
[
  {
    "key" : "test2",
    "desc": "desc2"
  },
  {
    "key" : "test3",
    "desc": "desc3"
  },
];
```

JS

```
this.save = function (newDataToStore) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        url : 'save.php',
        data : newDataToStore,
        success : function() {
            console.log("SUCCESS");
        },
        error : function() {
            console.log("ERROR");
        }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach:

1. You'll need to [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the JS-Object before sending it to the server:

   ```
   this.save = function (newDataToStore) {
       jQuery.ajax({
           type : "POST",
           dataType : "json",
           url : 'save.php',
           data : {'json': JSON.stringify(newDataToStore)},
           success : function() {
               console.log("SUCCESS");
           },
           error : function() {
               console.log("ERROR");
           }
      });
   }
   ```
2. On the serverside your script should do something like (as Mohammad Alabed pointed out):

   ```
   file_put_contents('/path/to/file1.json', $_POST['json']);
   ```

**BUT, beware**! Users could write arbitrary data to the file. You should always validate user input on the server side. (Maybe using a json schema)

Comment: Thanks, good piece of code but i get an exception : failed to open stream: Invalid argument on file_put_contents($_POST['json'], 'file1.json');

Comment: [file_put_contents](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) has a different order of attributes, sorry. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

in php file the json data will be in the post global variable because you use post in your ajax

so all what you need is `file_put_contents()`

**save.php**

```
file_put_contents('file1.json', json_encode($_POST));
```

by using this function you will write a new json string to your json file (old content will be deleted)

Answer (score 0):

in your save.php file

```
use json_decode()
```

it will decode your json datas passed from your ajax file